# Multiple inputs from the same line in java

Tags: java

I am in need of assistance with my Java program assignment. The assignment is to calculate the distance between two points using java. I completed part one as followed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceCalcEasy
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   // Creating a new scanner object
   System.out.println("Distance Calculator");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Getting all of the coordinates
   System.out.print("Enter the X coordinate of the first point: ");
   double x1 = input.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter the Y coordinate of the first point: ");
   double y1 = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter the X coordinate of the second point: ");
   double x2 = input.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter the Y coordinate of the second point: ");
   double y2 = input.nextDouble();

   // Calculating the distance between the points
   double distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2) );

   // Printing the distance to the User
   System.out.println("The distance between the points is " + distance);
   }
}
```

Now the problem is I need to do this same program again but the "hard way" by allowing the user to input a coordinate like 1,2 instead of each x and y on their own line. This is what I have started to come up with after a little bit of research:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceCalcHard
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Creating a new Scanner Object
      System.out.println("Distance Calculator");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Getting the data points
      System.out.print("Enter the first point x,y: ");
      String firstPoint = input.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter the second point x,y: ");
      String secondPoint = input.nextLine();

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(firstPoint).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
      while (scan.hasNextDouble() ) 
      { 

      }
      // Calculating the distance

      // Displaying the distance to the user
   }
}
```

Does that seem like a good start? I was thinking I could make two array's, one for each point, and then do my distance calculation that way. Is there a simpler way to do this or can someone point me in a better direction? Thank You

Comment: `int[] point1 = firstPoint.split(",")` give you the point in array, `[1, 2]` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceCalcEasy
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   // Creating a new scanner object
   System.out.println("Distance Calculator");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Getting all of the coordinates
   System.out.print("Enter the X,Y coordinate of the first point: ");
   String xy1in = input.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Enter the X,Y coordinate of the second point: ");
   String xy2in = input.nextLine();

   String[] xy1 = xy1in.split(",");
   String[] xy2 = xy2in.split(",");

   double x1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[0]);
   double y1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[1]);
   double x2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[0]);
   double y2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[1]);

   // Calculating the distance between the points
   double distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2) );

   // Printing the distance to the User
   System.out.println("The distance between the points is " + distance);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to go about splitting the string into two values (ie. x,y -> x and y) would be by using the `split()` operator for a `String` object.

```
String[] pointA = firstPoint.split(",");
```

And the same can be done for the second point. Now you have your two points in arrays where `pointA[0]` is the x value and `pointA[1]` is the y value.

More documentation about the method can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)